# Transform exported database data to XML

Tags: xml, database, transformation

I have exported data from database in this form:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
| name               | id           | field            |
+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
| name1              |            1 | field1           |
| name2              |            2 | field2           |
| name3              |            3 | field3           |
+--------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

and I need to transform them into xml form:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>name1</name>
        <id>1</id>
        <field>field1</field>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>name2</name>
        <id>2</id>
        <field>field2</field>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>name3</name>
        <id>3</id>
        <field>field3</field>
    </item>
</items>
```

What is the best way to do this transform?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT (
SELECT * 
FROM #TABLE_NAME
FOR XML PATH ('Item'), TYPE) FOR XML PATH('Items')
```

That would work on SQL Server.

If you're using mysql this link will help you find the way to change it to the correct sintax:

[SELECT ... FOR XML](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2410)